# LeetCode #617 "Merge Two Binary Trees" using C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

***The problem is:***

Given two binary trees and imagine that when you put one of them to cover the other, some nodes of the two trees are overlapped while the others are not.

You need to merge them into a new binary tree. The merge rule is that if two nodes overlap, then sum node values up as the new value of the merged node. Otherwise, the NOT null node will be used as the node of new tree.

```
Example 1:
Input: 
    Tree 1                     Tree 2                  
          1                         2                             
         / \                       / \                            
        3   2                     1   3                        
       /                           \   \                      
      5                             4   7                  
Output: 
Merged tree:
         3
        / \
       4   5
      / \   \ 
     5   4   7
```

Note: The merging process must start from the root nodes of both trees.

I try to solve this leetcode problem, but always get a wrong answer.

My answer is:

```
**Merged tree:
         3
        / \
       4   5
      /   
     5**
```

It seems that I lost the nodes 4 and 7.

However, from the std::cout, all nodes are created, but it seems the tree are not constructed.

I very appreciate for any comments on my code:

```
class Solution {

public:

TreeNode* mergeTrees(TreeNode* t1, TreeNode* t2) {
if (t1 == NULL && t2 == NULL)
    return NULL;
else if (t1 == NULL && t2 != NULL) {

    t1 = new TreeNode(t2->val);
    cout << "vq1:" << t1->val << endl;

    mergeTrees(t1->left, t2->left);
    mergeTrees(t1->right, t2->right);
}
else if (t1 != NULL && t2 == NULL) {
    t1->val += 0;
    cout << "vu1:" << t1->val << endl;
    mergeTrees(t1->left, NULL);
    mergeTrees(t1->right, NULL);
}
else if (t1 != NULL && t2 != NULL) {
    t1->val += t2->val;
    cout << "vx1:" << t1->val << endl;

    mergeTrees(t1->left, t2->left);
    mergeTrees(t1->right, t2->right);

}
return t1;
}
};
```

Comment: Please state your question exactly. What are you trying to achieve? what are you actually getting?

Comment: Step 1 - create a test case that demonstrates the problem;
Step 2 - read [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) site;
Step 3 - use a debugger and work out what's going on exactly

Comment: Just dismantle one of the trees, add its nodes to the other tree. There.

Comment: You never use the return values from the recursions, and never change the structure of `t1`. It also sounds like you're supposed to make an entirely new tree, not modify `t1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating nodes but not the left and right child of nodes try this,

```
TreeNode* mergeTrees(TreeNode* t1, TreeNode* t2) {

    if (t1 == NULL && t2 == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if (t1 == NULL && t2 != NULL) {

        t1 = new TreeNode(t2->val);
        cout << "vq1:" << t1->val << endl;

        t1->left = mergeTrees(t1->left, t2->left);
        t1->right = mergeTrees(t1->right, t2->right);
    }
    else if (t1 != NULL && t2 == NULL) {
        t1->val += 0;
        cout << "vu1:" << t1->val << endl;
        t1->left = mergeTrees(t1->left, NULL);
        t1->right = mergeTrees(t1->right, NULL);
    }
    else if (t1 != NULL && t2 != NULL) {
        t1->val += t2->val;
        cout << "vx1:" << t1->val << endl;

        t1->left = mergeTrees(t1->left, t2->left);
        t1->right = mergeTrees(t1->right, t2->right);

    }
    return t1;
}
```

Comment: I get your point. It is caused by that pointer **TreeNode* t1** (as input) is not a reference to the **first input argument** of the outter-layer recursion function mergeTrees(). In other words, ***t1 = new TreeNode(t2->val);*** does not create a link from the parent node to the child node.